# What is the correct way of displaying base64 image from database to php page?

Tags: php, html

I cannot figure out why my image is not displaying in my `index.php` page.

I use PDO to connect and use the database, but I faced some weird problem that has never happened to me before. The image that I stored in my database as **blob** type is not displaying in my `index.php` page.

Here's my code:

```
<?php    
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website;charset=utf8mb4';

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');

    if ( isset($_POST['upload']) ) 
    {         
        $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

        if ( !empty($file) ) 
        {               
            $sql = " INSERT INTO images(name) VALUES (:name) ";
            $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array('name' => $file));   
        }           
    }    
?>
```

This I use to display images on my **images** div tag:

```
<div class="images" id="Images">                
    <?php      
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM images ";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);

        if ( $result->rowCount() > 0 ) 
        {              
            while ( $row = $result->fetch() ) 
            {                    
                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,' .base64_encode($row['name']). '" alt="Binary Image"/>';   
            }   
        }                      
    ?>   
</div>
```

Comment: You are already altering the binary image data before passing it to the database by using `addslashes`. I would assume doing that is not what you want. Additionally when you store binary data in a blob field, mark the field as `BINARY` in the table schema (can't find the Q&A I had in mind for this right now).See as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6346319/367456 (2011), https://stackoverflow.com/q/14734812/367456 (2013) and [Large Objects (LOBs) - PDO manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the image directly encoded in base64 **an also its extension for proper display**.

**IMPORTANT**
The `content` field has to be TEXT type in your database, otherwise you won't store the data properly and you won't be able to get it as you should

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website;charset=utf8mb4';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get the image and convert into string
    $img = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    // Encode the image string data into base64
    $content = base64_encode($img);
    // Get the extension
    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name'])));
    if (!empty($content)) {
        $sql = " INSERT INTO images(content, extension) VALUES (:content, :extension) ";
        $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array('content' => $content, 'extension' => $extension));
    }
}

// Later in your code
?>
<div class="images" id="Images"></div>
    <?php
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM images ";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            echo "<img src='data:image/{$row['extension']};charset=utf-8;base64,{$row['content']}' alt='Binary Image'/>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```